# Interchange of expectation and limit

Tags: limits, expected-value, brownian-motion, random-walk

$E\left[ S_{t} \right] = E\left[ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{t/n}~R_{i}(t) \right]=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}E\left[ \sqrt{t/n}~R_{i}(t)  \right]=0$

Let $R_{1}(t),R_{2}(t),...,R_{n}(t)$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables with mean 0 and variance 1. e.g ±1 fair coin flips.
And $S_t=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{t/n}~R_{i}(t)$.
I am curious why we could interchange the summation and limit here. Could I apply monotone convergence theorem here? But the sequence $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{t/n}~R_{i}$ is not monotonically increasing, and it could be negative as well.

Comment: So the distribution of $R_i$ does not depend on $i$? Or do you mean $\sqrt{t/i}$ and $-\sqrt{t/i}$?

Comment: Oh, let me clarify, distribution of $R_i$ only depends on the total number of games, which is n in the above equation. And the coin is a fair coin, so fifty percent probability for head and fifty for tail after each independent toss. For each independent toss, if it's head you win $\sqrt{t/n}$, if it's tail then you lose that amount. And $S_t$ is basically the cumulative of winnings, and it starts with 0.

Comment: I used $\sqrt(t/n)$ here so the variance of $S(t)$ would always be t.

Comment: So how do you take the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n R_i(t)$? Do you generate a separate $n$-game run for each value of $n$?

Comment: It's taught in my financial engineering class. Forgive me if I didn't understand that quite well, but my understanding of that is that if you generate a run of infinite times of games in a given time t (the total time t is fixed, and if n is large enough, then the time for each game t/n is going to be very small, basically the purpose is to make the whole process continuous), and you take the expectation of the cumulative winnings for the n games.

Comment: The only way I can conceive of this making sense is by re-interpreting $R_i(t)$ as $\sqrt{t/n} R_i$ where $R_i$ are i.i.d. $\pm 1$ fair coin flips.  Otherwise, you run into the problem of how to even interpret the limit defining $S_t$ (for instance, if the limit is only in distribution, then there's nothing to show, but we wouldn't know that from the given question)

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are exactly right. What I am trying to do here is to create a symmetrical random walk in continuous time with mean of 0 and variance of t. Yet when I am trying to prove that the mean = 0, I met this trouble of why I can interchange the expectation and limit.

Comment: Are you just trying to prove an instance of [Donsker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem)?  If so, you probably should use the form given in that theorem.

Comment: That seems like it, thank you.